# Unable to quit Asterisk CLI using exit or quit

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, asterisk, exit

I started Asterisk CLI with the below command:

```
asterisk -vvvvvvc
```

When I try to exit CLI using exit or quit, I see the errors below:

```
*CLI> exit
No such command 'exit' (type 'core show help exit' for other possible commands)
*CLI> quit
No such command 'quit' (type 'core show help quit' for other possible commands)
```

I am able to exit CLI using `^C`. Why is exit and quit not working?

Answer (score 7):

As the error message states, there is no "exit" or "quit" command. But there is an entry in the Asterisk wiki discussing how to stop Asterisk from the CLI: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Stopping+and+Restarting+Asterisk+From+The+CLI

The command you should be using is "core stop" (note, however, that this actually kills asterisk, not only the shell) and you have a few options available for it:

```
*CLI> help core stop
core stop gracefully           -- Gracefully shut down Asterisk
core stop now                  -- Shut down Asterisk immediately
core stop when convenient      -- Shut down Asterisk at empty call volume
```

In any case, by starting asterisk with the -c flag you are not starting it as a service, but in foreground, meaning that you have to leave your shell open if you want Asterisk to continue running.

You should be starting it without the -c flag and then use -r to connect to it: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Connecting+to+the+Asterisk+CLI

Then you can just quit the "remote shell" by using ^C. Asterisk will keep running in background. I personally like to use daemontools to start and supervise services: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svc.html.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You should start the `asterisk` daemon first. Then connect to the console.:

Starting the daemon is as simple as:

```
$>asterisk
```

Then you can connect to the console with all the verbosity:

```
$>asterisk -rvvvvvv
```

I don't believe there is any graceful exit using `asterisk -c` as you have.

Comment: `core stop gracefully` exits from console after stopping asterisk service. Then following the commands as you listed should work. `asterisk -c` actually starts a process in foreground. Anyway, the combined solution from you and the accepted answer make more sense. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in the foreground, if you started Asterisk such as:

```
asterisk -gcvvvvvvvvv
```

If you try the quit command, it won't work, because you are running in the foreground.

Try to connect to the Asterisk console running in background, then use quit or exit:

```
[root@localhost asterisk]# asterisk -rvvv

localhost*CLI> exit
```

-r: Connect to Asterisk running in the background and present a Asterisk CLI

-v: The verbose command. Add more ‘v’:s to get more messages.

Output:

> Asterisk cleanly ending (0). Executing last minute cleanups

To check if asterisk is running:

```
[root@localhost asterisk]# ps -ef | grep asterisk
```

To stop the Asterisk process:

```
cli> core stop now
```

To start the Asterisk service:

```
 [root@localhost asterisk]# service asterisk start
```

To stop the Asterisk service:

```
 [root@localhost asterisk]# service asterisk stop
```